# Diff of a diff? Major patch 1 vs Major patch 2. Then New patch 1 vs Major patch 2 subtract previous diff

Tags: diff, git-diff

Is it possible to diff 2 files. Say version 1.0 and version 2.0 of a software. Creating a reasonably sized diff. Then diff a patch vs version 2.0 of the software which also includes diffs from version 1.0.  So essentially subtract the diff of ver1 ver2 from the diff of patch ver2.

Example I want to diff a patch applied to a soft at its version 1.0 stage, but vs the version 2.0.  If I do diff patch vs ver2.  The diff is huge because of all the changes from ver1 to ver2.    So i want to diff ver1 ver2, then subtract this diff from the diff of patch ver2.

Comment: Not really sure if this would work off the top of my head, or if it's the easiest solution... but you could try checking out version 2, cherrypicking the patch you want to see then running diff?

Comment: The problem is I dont have a commit tree. Its just 3 flat files.  Non-git projects.